# How to redefine / override the behavior and the life cycle of a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, lifecycle

I always read about the possibility of rewriting a new definition for the smart pointers behavior, but still today i can't find a real example.

Now I want to propose this problem and see if I can get a solution:

Smart pointers are using reference counting or reference linking to manage their lifetime cycle, my basic problem consist in adding a new state that can cause the release and the deletion of my pointers, I would like to free my resources when an event is triggered.

It's more or less like when playing a game, usually all the resources are loaded and freed when the user is passing from the level 1 to the level 2, so when this happen the resources from the level 1 are freed. Also I would like to stick with this example because you can't wait for the automatic reference counting and maybe think that, ok if in the level 2 a resource from the level 1 is not used it will be automatically freed because it's no longer requested; this can be true but operating with the memory when an user is using the machine under stress is a really bad move.

I would like to stick with the smart pointers because I am also interested in all the other features that they offer, but they have this big downside for me and I need to manage their life cycle in a direct way.

What options do I have ?

Comment: If you have a "Level" object, then keeping the right objects when changing levels will be easy.

Comment: @mfontanini yes but the problem is how to free the others, and how to do this in the meantime when there is the change of levels and not waiting for the automatism.

Comment: How about observer pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: @ForEveR this is a good design solution for the architecture of my software, but in the end i still have to deal with the smart pointer behavior if i want to manage my objects in the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just threw in a bunch of shared pointers and didn't bother thinking proper about ownership of the resources. From the description it seems clear to me that the level object should own all these resources. That means they should *not be shared*, and thus no reference counting is needed at all.

Using smart pointers frees you from the burden of releasing the resources manually at the appropriate time, but it doesn't free you from thinking about what the appropriate time is.

If I am correct and level should own the resources, use a smart pointer that gives unique ownership, or just use automatic objects and don't even bother with smart pointers. Every other object except the level that needs access to those objects needs a non-owning pointer or reference to it, i.e., a traditional pointer or reference.

If I am wrong and the resources should indeed be shared, then they should not be released when the level is destroyed: the other objects that were sharing ownership will not like it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have shared-pointers remaining after a level is finished, that should be due to the fact that the shared-pointers were not allocated as automatic variables on the stack of functions called during the life-time of the level, but rather are stored in some type of container or series of globally accessible containers.  Thus the main issue you need to be concerned with is managing the life-cycle of the containers containing the shared-pointers that manage the resources for each level.

For instance, a smart-pointer allocated on the stack inside some function `foo` will only have a life-time the corresponds to the duration of the function call.  Once the function call is complete, then the shared-pointer is destroyed.  If there are additional shared-pointers still pointing to a resource, then the resource itself won't be destroyed, but those additional shared-pointers need to be residing in some other location other than the stack of the callee.  So your job is to manage those "other locations", which I'm guessing are most likely some series of globally accessible containers.

Therefore flushing the containers that mange the data for each level should in-turn completely destroy the allocated resources for each level.  If you want, you could use an event-driven interface or simple observer pattern for triggering the flush of the containers, or it could simply be done explicitly by the destructor for an object that manages the life-time of level resources.

In the end though it comes down to resource management ... just because a shared-pointer is designed to prevent memory leaks does not mean you shouldn't keep track of how or where they are allocated.  If you centralize the storage of your shared pointers, then destroying the resources they manage will not be that big a deal.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, shared pointers for your particular problem might not be the right solution. However, you can still manage manually their destruction if you'd like to time slice the freeing up of your level for example (or maybe even wait later when you have some spare CPU cycles if the memory pressure isn't too high or a concern). Once you are done with a resource, simple queue it up for destruction in a global queue (or several queues, perhaps one per type or by priority, etc.). Later on simply process that queue and remove the references. This will trigger the object's destruction if it is indeed the last reference to it. You could easily check a timer every few iterations for example and check that once you've spent 1ms freeing stuff, quit and continue on the next frame.

Performance wise, using memory pools per level (or per asset package) makes more sense. It makes for easier memory management and you can sometimes get away with freeing the whole pool at once and skip calling the destructors on all the objects within (if you know they do nothing!).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you really shouldn't be using shared pointers at all.  There are ways to override the behaviors by specifying custom deallocators but I would consider a different type of "smart pointer".

The Apache web server uses memory pools to deallocate all of the resources associated with a request by having the request own a pool of memory.  When you allocate memory inside of the server, you are required to identify the pool that you want to allocate from.  The server maintains a handful of memory pools each with a different lifetime - one for the server instance, another for the module, another for each request, etc.  This sounds like a better match to your situation.

The Apache code uses their [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/modules.html) for memory management.  It is written in C and might not be the best match for what you are doing.  It does look like Boost has a memory pool library as well though I have never used it.